# I am getting: "No such file or directory: 'data.xlsx'" error message, even though I have my python file in the same file as the Excel file

Tags: excel, pandas

Here is the error I get and I don't know what's the problem.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.getcwd()` to find out what the current working directory is for python.

```
import os
os.getcwd()
cd my_desired_directory
```

or just set your directory:

```
os.chdir("desired_directory_from_root")
```

Comment: the third line is incorrect. Probably you missed a sentence in between.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Complete path of the file for reading it. For example:

```
C:/Users/ihovl/helloworld/.vscode/data.xlsx
```

or something like that. Find the path of the file exactly and pass it to the `pd.ExcelFile`